# React error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs

I'm getting the following error from React and my page isn't loading: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

It happens when I use `import` declarations at the top of my React component, such as `import React from "react"`.

According to this question on Stack Overflow, the answer is to change `module.exports = ComponentName` to `export default ComponentName`, but in my case both pieces of code throw the same error.

Can someone help me figure out what is causing the error?

Register.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const Register = () => {
  return (
    <div>registration page</div>
  )
}
export default Register
```

webpack.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  context: path.join(__dirname, './'),
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        // loader: 'jsx-loader',
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the file in which you're referencing `Register.jsx`?

Comment: The problem is probably with your import statement that imports the `Register` component; could you share that please?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk that was it. I was referencing it in the main App.jsx file as `const Register = require("./Register.jsx")`, instead of as `import Register from "./Register.jsx"`. Once I changed it to import, it worked Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @tkore Yep, that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're likely importing incorrectly. Since you're exporting as default, change your import from:

```
import { Register } from '<some_path>/Register';
```

to:

```
import Register from '<some_path>/Register';
```

or CommonJS style:

```
const Register = require('<some_path>/Register');
```

to

```
const Register = require('<some_path>/Register').default;
```